# Database Help on creating procedure

Tags: mysql, database

Hello I am trying to create a procedure using Oracle My SQL Developer

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
    ProductID int, 
    ProductName varchar2(100),  
    ProductFinish varchar2(100), 
    ProductStandardPrice int, 
    ProductLineID int, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ProductID));
```

The data being inserted

```
    INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, ProductName, ProductFinish, ProductStandardPrice, ProductLineID) VALUES (1, 'End Table', 'Cherry', 175, 1);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, ProductName, ProductFinish, ProductStandardPrice, ProductLineID) VALUES (2, 'Coffee Table', 'Natural Ash', 200, 2);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, ProductName, ProductFinish, ProductStandardPrice, ProductLineID) VALUES (3, 'Computer Desk', 'Natural Ash', 375, 2);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, ProductName, ProductFinish, ProductStandardPrice, ProductLineID) VALUES (4, 'Entertainment Center', 'Natural Maple', 650, 3);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, ProductName, ProductFinish, ProductStandardPrice, ProductLineID) VALUES (5, 'Writers Desk', 'Cherry', 325, 1);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, ProductName, ProductFinish, ProductStandardPrice, ProductLineID) VALUES (6, '8-Drawer Desk', 'White Ash', 750, 2);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, ProductName, ProductFinish, ProductStandardPrice, ProductLineID) VALUES (7, 'Dining Table', 'Natural Ash', 800, 2);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, ProductName, ProductFinish, ProductStandardPrice, ProductLineID) VALUES (8, 'Computer Desk', 'Walnut', 250, 3);
```

And the procedure im trying to create

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProductLineSale
AS
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN ProductStandardPrice >= 400 THEN (ProductStandardPrice * 0.9)
ELSE (ProductStandardPrice * 0.85)
END AS SalePrice
FROM product
GO;

EXEC ProductLineSale;
```

At Select *
I am getting that error. Would you please offer help. I'm still new to this.

Edit: The procedure that was proposed works, however, I am still quite stuck. 
The procedure is in an invalid state so I cannot call it and 
I am trying to access the database from JSP via Netbeans.

Forgive my many mistakes, and here is my code from Netbeans

```
<%@ page import = "java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import = "java.io.*"%>
<% Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>JSP Page connected successfully!</h1>
        <%

            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@129.7.240.3:1521:ORCL";

            Connection basic = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "myname", "myname#");

            Statement statement = basic.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM myname.PRODUCT");

        %>


        <table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" align="center" bgcolor="#999999">
            <TR>
                <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'> <font size='2'/>ProductID</TH>
                <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'> <font size='2'/>ProductNAME</TH>
                <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'> <font size='2'/>ProductFINISH</TH>
                <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'> <font size='2'/>ProductSTANDARDPRICE</TH>
                <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'> <font size='2'/>ProductLINEID</TH>
            <TR>
                <% while (result.next()) {%>
            <TR>
                <TD> <font size='2'/><center><%= result.getString(1)%></center<>/TD> 
                call ProductLineSale();
        </TR>

        <% }%>
    </table>
    <h1>Table supposed to be above this<h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: You are using ms sql server, but https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4d8d9ad8924012a860c7ed42f96ff99e  show no error whatsover . So please provide us with the exact error message

Comment: I don't see anything procedural here, so why do you want a procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for creating a procedure is not correct for MySQL. You need to indicate the parameters (none in your case), and remove the `AS`. Since you only have one statement, you don't *need* a `BEGIN` and `END` to surround it, but I have included them in case you expand the procedure in the future. Note that dependent on the environment in which you enter the procedure, you may or may not need the `DELIMITER` statements.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ProductLineSale ()
BEGIN
  SELECT *,
         CASE WHEN ProductStandardPrice >= 400 THEN (ProductStandardPrice * 0.9)
              ELSE (ProductStandardPrice * 0.85)
         END AS SalePrice
  FROM Product;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

To run the procedure, use a `CALL` statement:

```
CALL ProductLineSale()
```

Output for your sample data:

```
ProductID   ProductName     ProductFinish   ProductStandardPrice    ProductLineId   SalePrice
1           End Table       Cherry          175                     1               148.75
2           Coffee Table    Natural Ash     200                     2               170.00
3           Computer Desk   Natural Ash     375                     2               318.75
4           Entertainment   Natural Maple   650                     3               585.0
5           Writers Desk    Cherry          325                     1               276.25
6           8-Drawer Desk   White Ash       750                     2               675.0
7           Dining Table    Natural Ash     800                     2               720.0
8           Computer Desk   Walnut          250                     3               212.50
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=00f002cc285db1080342628e75c2496d)

Comment: Ok, so the procedure that you have given have worked good. However when I call it, it tells me it is in an invalid state.

I am trying to put this in the Oracle SQL developer and run it on the web via netbeans.

So far the code which im going to edit above is where I am.

Comment: @JeremySNero that is a completely different question related to netbeans programming, not the MySQL procedure you wanted help with. If this solved your original problem, you should mark it accepted and ask a new question about the programming issues, referring back to this question as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No, actually the procedure I'm making was for a table in MySQL Developer. I was using it for an assignment where I run a procedure on a table to calculate Sale Total. Then I would go on to display that table on a JSP using netbeans. I got stuck someway through, but I was able to get through it. Thank you again for the help.